# Spring webmvc load static resources

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I have the following project structure:

```
myApp:
   -resources
       -css
       -js
       -others
   -Java resources
   -WebContent
```

How can I link CSS file from my JSPs ?
And how can i get the path of others folders to save files in it?
I'm using tomcat7.
i have this in my configuration file

```
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**"></mvc:resources>
```

and tried to refer files as:

```
  <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/something.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Everything was fine as long as I had my resource folder in my WebContent folder but it seems is not a good practice.
i tried

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath()
```

for saving the file but it directs me to my tomcat folder and I'm not sure it's ok to save large files there

Comment: the way you have it now is fine, where are you getting 'resource folder in WebContent folder is not good practice' from ? surely css/images etc should be in the WebContent section rather than Java Resources etc ?

Comment: When you save a document from MS Word or LibreOffice or whatever, does it save the document inside the msword.exe file? No, it doesn't. It saves it in "My Documents", which is a folder where user data is being stored, separate from the application files. Deinstalling and reinstalling Office won't make you lose all your documents, and that's quite an important thing to have, isn't it? Then why do you want to do that with your Java webapp? Save files OUTSIDE of the application, which BTW is a read-only war file. Choose a directory where files are saved, outside of the app, and save them there.

Comment: ok.1) so is it ok to save inside tomcat installation folder ?2)so i didn't quite understand if it's ok to have my css/images/js in webcontent or not

Comment: 3) how can i set my savedImages folder( let's say) relative to my project so it would be ok if i deploy my app on server ? post it as an answer please so i can accept it

Comment: 4) by the way, i will later need to access those files, to load them in my jsps for example